# Ionic 4 pass property to custom component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I've written a custom component to handle my ion-header as all I need to change per page is the title. However, the title is not displaying as the component doesn't seem to be getting the property from the app page.

Component Template

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-toolbar color="primary">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
  </ion-buttons>
<ion-title> {{title}} </ion-title>
```

Component Typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './custom-toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-toolbar.component.scss'],
})
export class CustomToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title: any;

  constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

App Page Template

```
<app-custom-toolbar [title]="Dashboard"></app-custom-toolbar>
```

Comment: I think if you have the `[]` around it then to pass a string back you would need `"'dashboard'"` (so a `"` with a `'` inside it).

Comment: @rtpHarry that solved it I knew it was something simple. Can you post that as an answer so I can make it as answered? Thanks

Comment: :) I've added it as an answer... I appreciate the offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting my comment as requested:

I think if you have the `[]` around it then to pass a string back you would need `"'dashboard'"` (so a `"` with a `'` inside it).

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `@Input() title` in your custom component to pass value from parent into it like -

Child Component

```
...

...

@Input() title: any;

...

...
```

Parent Component HTML -

```
<child-component [title]="somePropertyInParentComponent"></child-component>
```

Edit: According to your updated question . Try removing [] from the title property in parent component

Comment: I've tried that however its not working. I've updated the original question with that code included Thanks

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the DOM to see if the value is there or not in the ion-title? It will clear out if there is some rendering issue or not .

Answer (score 1):

As Pawan Sharma says, you need to declare an @Input,
In this link you can find more information about it.
https://victorroblesweb.es/2016/11/07/input-output-angular-2/

Typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footertoolbar',
  templateUrl: './footertoolbar.page.html',
})
export class FooterToolbarPage implements OnInit {

  @Input() public activeIndex:number;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) { }
  ngOnInit() {}

  public GoToPage() { console.log(this.activeIndex); }  
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-buttons class="sidemargin" slot="secondary">                      
       <ion-button (click)="GoToPage()"></ion-button>               
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
```

HTML of the component that use the component

```
<app-footertoolbar [activeIndex]="0" >
</app-footertoolbar>
```